# How to insert data into many to many table in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, insert, many-to-many

I am new in Laravel 
I have two tables Student , Courses .
Their relation is many to many, when I try to  add new student and assign the student to many courses that already exist  , it add new student correctly but can`t add to table student_course 
I use Laravel 5.7 .

In Student Model I  define function courses

```
           public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course');
    }
```

And in Courses model I add

```
   public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Student');
}
```

In studentController

```
    public function store(Request $request , Courses courses)
{

    Student::createStudent($request->all());
    $courses = courses()->attach($request->courses);
    return redirect('/admin/student')->with('success','Has been added');
}
```

In student create.blade

```
  <select name='courses[]' style="width:220px;" multiple="multiple">
                        @foreach( $courses as $course )
                        <option value="{{$course->id}}">{{$course->name_courses}}</option>
                      @endforeach
                      </select>
```

This to select many courses.

The error that occurred  that the courses is undefine variable in StudentController. 
I try to solve it but I have no idea how to.

Comment: Post the code as text not image.

Comment: It`s worked , Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Felippe Duarte

Comment: This isn't many to many relationship. You need 3 tables for that. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: @DaliaNajeh how did you solved it? you didn't provide what solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should be your store function:

```
public function store(Request $request,Courses courses){
    $student = Student::createStudent($request->all());
    $courses = Course::find($request->get('courses'));
    $student->courses()->attach($courses);
    return redirect('/admin/student')->with('success','Has been added'); 
}
```